# C#/While infinite loop

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, while-loop, infinite-loop

i have some kind of app which monitor CPU and Memory usage.When I put this:

```
double currentMemFree = (int)perfMemCount.NextValue();
progBarMem.Value = (int)(totMem1 - currentMemFree);
double currentCpuPercentage = (int)perfCpuCount.NextValue();
progBarCpu.Value = (int)currentCpuPercentage;
```

normally next to Initializecomponent(); It works,but it just load mem usage at start and this value is there 4ever.When i write it like this :

```
    while(true)
{
double currentMemFree = (int)perfMemCount.NextValue();
progBarMem.Value = (int)(totMem1 - currentMemFree);
double currentCpuPercentage = (int)perfCpuCount.NextValue();
progBarCpu.Value = (int)currentCpuPercentage;
Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

The program doesn't start.It start debugging but the program doesn't start.When i hit F5,down at the "status" panel is written : Loading symbols for... and this stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Good time to learn **Task**s http://dotnetcodr.com/2014/01/01/5-ways-to-start-a-task-in-net-c/

Answer (score 1):

It's because of this line `Thread.Sleep(1000);` That causes your thread to sleep for 1 second and it never stops sleeping because of the infinite loop. You have to put this logic outside the UI thread, so the update happens on a background thread without interfering with your UI.

There are many ways you can handle this... For instance Threads, BackgroundWorker, Task, async/await... All have their pros and cons. Do some research, try them out and pick the one which suits your needs the most.

Comment: Thanks.I am newbie so I don't know all of this stuff you said but I'll try to google it :)